# How to solve: SQLException: no such table: locations: ALTER TABLE "locations" ADD "user_id" integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I'm having some DB issues with rails. When I run `rails db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
add_column(:locations, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: locations: ALTER TABLE "locations" ADD "user_id" integer
```

The problem seems to be that I have a migration that is trying to add `:user_id` to a table `:locations` but this table does not exist because I deleted it and it is therefore not in the schema. How do I solve this? I always thought it was a bad idea to delete migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Was `locations` created and deleted by migrations? If so, is the failing migration, in time terms, between those migrations?. If the answer is *yes* then you should not delete it.

In the other hand, if you deleted `locations` by hand or by migration **before** the failing migration then remove it, since it makes no sense to your schema.

Comment: the `locations` table was created by `rails g model Location` but there doesn't seem to be a migration file for it. Maybe I somehow deleted it when I was trying to delete the table from the schema.

If i delete a migration do I just manually delete the file? Or is there some command I should use?

Comment: Just delete the file.